# Angular download pdf with Web API 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

We are trying to download a file from a web api v2 and then either use a 'Save As' OR automatically download in browser any solution would be fine but cannot get any to work.

What is happening in Chrome is nothing, doesn't do a thing
In IE we get a prompt 'do you want to allow this website to open an application on your computer?' click allow and then nothing happens at all.

Here is the WebAPI controller code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{pdf}/{getPDF}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetPDF()
    {
        var outputpath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");
        HttpResponseMessage result;

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(outputpath + "Inv_008618_180868_33687.pdf", FileMode.Open))
        {
            result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StreamContent(stream),                     
            };

            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "Inv_008618_180868_33687.pdf",
                Size = stream.Length
            };

            return Ok(result);

        }
    }
```

I think the above code is correct not 100% sure though as the filesize is very small.

Here is the Angular code:

```
getPDF: function () {
            var scope = this;
            var urlApi = 'http://localhost:59242/supplier/pdf/';

            return $http({
                url: urlApi,
                responseType: 'arraybuffer'
            }).then(function (response) {
                    var file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });                        
                    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

                    var pdf = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);

                    //var element = angular.element('<a/>');
                    //element.attr({
                    //    href: 'data:attachment/pdf;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(response),
                    //    target: '_self',
                    //    download: 'test.pdf'
                    //})[0].click();

                    window.open(pdf);
              }

                            return response.data;
                        })
                        .catch(function (err) {
                        })
        }
```

I would like to thank you for replying

Comment: What happens if you call the blob constructor with response.data: `var file = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });` ?

Comment: Hi peco solved the problem using ngFileSaver thanks

Answer (score 1):

solved the problem using ngFileSaver thanks